# Help identifying spokes

Tags: spokes

Ordered some Halo spokes for a wheel rebuild. Spokes arrived without packaging and have an unfamiliar stamping. From my other wheel build I remember Halo having capital "H" stamped on spoke heads.
Did Halo change the logo or was I sold wrong spokes?

[image]

Comment: That logo doesn't show up on this page (http://www.mrrabbit.net/docs/spokeheads/main.html) of spoke logos, not even as unknown.  The page looks like it's a bit out of date, but I can't find a more current reference.

Comment: Thanks DavidW. I've checked there too

Comment: Is the question about identifying the manufacturer, or confirming if the spokes fit the wheel?

Comment: @ojs, I want to identify the manufacturer. Spoke dimensions are what I have ordered. But I paid for specific brand and I have a suspicion what has been delivered is a cheaper lower quality spoke.

Comment: If in doubt, why not just return them saying they aren't what you ordered then go to a more reputable retailer?

Comment: Sometimes the product page gives clues about the chances of the product being fake. Gramatical errors, or not using the brand name anywhere in the title or description, but only in photos which are just for reference, inacurrate product description, etc. Is it a reputable seller with good reviews? Do they have a return policy?

Comment: I recommend emailing Halo about it. They'll likely just tell you what's up. Halo to my awareness is a 100% design/marketing/importing company with no production capacity of their own - that doesn't make their products bad, but it does mean that changing suppliers in a pinch for something like this is a thing that could happen, and maybe the stamping tooling wasn't in the right place at the right time. Or it could just be a new logo.

Comment: @Hursey, that would not be very fair on the retailer if it turns out that Halo just used a different stamp on a batch of spokes. I am genuinely trying to understand what are these spokes. Especially if I come accross them again in the future. I have now sent an email to Halo for clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have received a response from the manufacturer:

> Hi Art,
>
> Thank you for your email. We use a few different manufacturers for different > spoke SKU’s. These do look like a stamp from us, so they should be legitimate.
>
> Kind regards,

Mystery solved. These appear to be Halo spokes. Credit to @Nathan Knutson
for advising to contact the manufacturer.